# Update SQL for Oracle when more then two tables are involved - ORA-00933

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am relatively new to writing SQL.  I have written the following:

```
UPDATE PS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES C
SET C.EMAIL_ADDR = B.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR
 FROM PS_LOAN_ORIGNATN A, PS_SFA_COD_BORROWR B
 WHERE A.EMPLID <> A.BORR_EMPLID
    AND A.AID_YEAR = '2019'
    AND A.ACAD_CAREER = 'UGRD'
    AND A.BORR_EMPLID <> ' '
    AND B.SFA_CR_AWARD_YEAR = A.AID_YEAR
    AND B.SFA_CR_ID_SSN = A.BORR_SSN
    AND B.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR <> ' '
    AND B.SFA_CR_DOCUMENT_ID = (SELECT MAX( D.SFA_CR_DOCUMENT_ID)
 FROM PS_SFA_COD_BORROWR D
 WHERE D.SFA_CR_AWARD_YEAR = B.SFA_CR_AWARD_YEAR
    AND D.SFA_CR_ID_SSN = B.SFA_CR_ID_SSN
    AND D.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR <> ' ')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
 FROM PS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES C
 WHERE C.EMPLID = A.BORR_EMPLID
    AND C.E_ADDR_TYPE = 'PEM'
    AND C.EMAIL_ADDR <> B.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR)
```

But checking it on SQL Fiddle, I get ORA-00933. I may not be asking it right, but I have been working through different versions.

Comment: Oracle `UPDATE` doesn't take a `FROM` clause, so your query makes no sense.  Are you sure you are using Oracle?  If you are, sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I will provide that as soon as I am able.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:  That isnt Oracle Sql syntax, you have reused the alias C, and your indenting is a bit hard to follow.

See if this works for you:

```
UPDATE PS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES E
   SET E.EMAIL_ADDR = (SELECT B.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR
  FROM PS_LOAN_ORIGNATN A, PS_SFA_COD_BORROWR B
 WHERE A.EMPLID <> A.BORR_EMPLID
   AND A.AID_YEAR = '2019'
   AND A.ACAD_CAREER = 'UGRD'
   AND A.BORR_EMPLID <> ' '
   AND B.SFA_CR_AWARD_YEAR = A.AID_YEAR
   AND B.SFA_CR_ID_SSN = A.BORR_SSN
   AND B.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR <> ' '
   AND B.SFA_CR_DOCUMENT_ID = (SELECT MAX( D.SFA_CR_DOCUMENT_ID)
                                 FROM PS_SFA_COD_BORROWR D
                                WHERE D.SFA_CR_AWARD_YEAR = B.SFA_CR_AWARD_YEAR
                                  AND D.SFA_CR_ID_SSN = B.SFA_CR_ID_SSN
                                  AND D.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR <> ' ')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM PS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES C
                WHERE C.EMPLID = A.BORR_EMPLID
                  AND C.E_ADDR_TYPE = 'PEM'
                  AND C.EMAIL_ADDR <> B.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, Vinnie.  I am trying to learn and examples do help.  I may have bitten off more than I can chew on this one.   I will check it out.

Comment: Vinnie, I get "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" when using that SQL oddly enough.  I am running this in Campus Solutions 9.0 PeopleSoft.  What I am trying to do, is update already existing emails (table PS_EMAIL_ADDRESSES.EMAIL_ADDR) if there is new email address in PS_SFA_BORROWR.SFA_CR_EMAIL_ADDR.  However, there are times where there can be more than one row of data per applicant which is why I want to use the max on PS_SFA_BORROWR.SFA_CR_DOCUMENT_ID.

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple rows in PS_SFA_COD_BORROWR with the same SFA_CR_DOCUMENT_ID?

Comment: It is very well possible that could be occurring.  Normally it wouldn't but there may be cases were an application could get completed twice.  I would use an analytical function such as FIRST_VALUE, but I've found through trial and error and research that Windowed Functions and Updates do not mix well. It works fine in a Select.

Comment: The problem is that you are setting a single column to what should be a single value, but your query allows multiple values (from multiple rows) to be returned.